# Procedure to pressure test a boiler for cracks?

Tags: heating, water-heater, boiler, central-heating

What is the procedure to pressure test a house heater boiler, and the rest of the system? My plan is to remove any broken radiators and put in place a temporary PEX line between the inlet/outlet so the system can flow as it typically does.

I'm rebuilding a house that had some freeze damage and a few of the radiators cracked due to freezing. The boiler itself is in the basement and seems it may have not been damaged as the rest of the water pipes throughout the basement did not break. The boiler is oil fired and looks to be in good shape overall. The system was drained at some point after the initial system freeze and has been sitting for a year or two.

What is the common procedure and where is the air pressure best added into the system? A plumber told me they use 10-15 psi of air when testing systems. I asked about water pressure and he said its standard they use air for testing, not water.

If the system holds pressure and is not cracked, I will then call an actual HVAC company to get the system back up and running, but I'd like to do my own first round of tests to see if the boiler core itself is viable.

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Since water is essentially incompressible, it is better to fill with water and add the extra pressure with gas (air). Limits the stored energy if something gives way.

Comment: @JonCuster, great point. I believe the system typically runs around 10 psi. If adding air to the normal water level to reach 15psi, at what point would I introduce the air into the system, at the main relief valve outlet? The plumber said they use air and leave it for a few hours.

Comment: Would probably need a tee added with an air pig(tire valve) mounted on it.  If a drain valve is handy some air pigs will screw right on to the faucet.

Comment: Thanks @crip659, I bought a few different style threaded connectors to make up something I can hook on and introduce some air into the system after I get the water pressure to where it needs to be. If anyone has other tips on anything I'm open to more feedback.